# ORA-01722: invalid number with package

Tags: sql, oracle

I have looked through numerous thread but I still don't have the answer.

I ran  script before that tells sql developer to act as discoverer(a package that has been created), however when running the query it returns ORA-01722: invalid number.

I have selected from the package against dual and it returns the value.

could someone point me in the right direction of why it is returning this error message?

```
 select gsb.name       "Set of Books Name"
,       gsb.set_of_books_id         "Set of Books Id"
,       gjb.name                    "Batch Name"
,       gjh.name                    "Journal Name"
,       trunc(gjh.date_created)     "Journal Header Date Created"     
,       gjh.status                  "Journal Header Status"   
,       gcc.segment1                "Company"
,       gcc.segment7                "Interco Code"
,       APT.term_id                 "Term ID"
,       APT.Name                    "Type of Term"    
,       APT.Description             "Term Decription"
,       ffvt3.description           "Intercompany Descr"
,       gcc.segment2                "Natural Account Code" 
,       ffvt.description            "Natural Account Descr"
,       gcc.segment3                "Cost Centre Code"
,       ffvt2.description           "Cost Centre Descr"
,       gjl.je_line_num             "Je Line Num"
,       gjh.currency_code           "Currency Code"
,       gjl.description             "Line Description"
,       gjh.period_name             "Period Name"
,       gpd.period_num              "Period Num"
,       gpd.period_year             "Period Year"
,       gjc.user_je_category_name   "Category Name"
,       gjs.user_je_source_name     "Source Name"
,       gjl.status                  "Line Status"
,       gjh.actual_flag             "Actual Flag"
,       nvl(gjl.accounted_dr,0)     "Acctd Dr"
,       nvl(gjl.accounted_cr,0)     "Acctd Cr"
,       trunc(gjh.posted_date)      "GL Date"
,       gjl.attribute3              "Recon Status"
,       gjl.effective_date          "Line GL Date"
,       gjl.reference_1             "Reference1"
,       gjl.reference_4             "Reference4"
,       gjl.reference_2             "Invoice Id"
,       pov.vendor_name             "Vendor Name"
,       pov.segment1               "Vendor Number"
,     CASE
        WHEN gjl.reference_6 = 'CUSTOMER' 
        THEN gjl.reference_4
        ELSE gjl.reference_5 
      END                           "Invoice Num" 
,       gjh.doc_sequence_value      "Doc Num"
,       gjh.doc_sequence_value      "Journal Voucher Num"
,       api.invoice_date            "Invoice Date"
,       api.voucher_num             "Image Num"
,       api.discount_amount_taken   "discount amount"
,       api.attribute1              "PO Number"
,       api.attribute2              "GRN Number"
,       api.attribute3              "Invoice Approver"
,       pvs.vendor_site_code        "Vendor Site Code"
,       gjl.code_combination_id     "Code Combination Id"
,       gcc.concatenated_segments   "Full Account Code"
,       api.amount_paid             "Amount Paid"
,       api.base_amount             "Base Amount"
,       api.creation_date           "Creation Date"
,       api.description             "AP Inv Description"
,       api.invoice_amount          "Invoice Amount"
,       api.invoice_type_lookup_code "Invoice Type"
,       api.source "Invoice Source"
,       gjh.posted_date             "Posted Date"
,       aca.check_date              "Payment Date"
,       aca.check_number        "Payment Number"
,       case when gjl.reference_6 = 'CUSTOMER' then gjl.reference_4
             else null 
        end                         "Trans Number"
,       case when gjl.reference_6 = 'CUSTOMER' then 
             (select distinct customer_name
            from ar_customers_v
               where customer_number = gjl.reference_5) 
             else null 
        end                          "Customer Name"
from    gl_je_batches               gjb
,       gl_je_headers               gjh
,       gl_je_lines                 gjl
,       gl_periods                  gpd
,       gl_code_combinations_kfv    gcc
,       gl_sets_of_books            gsb
,       gl_je_categories_tl         gjc
,       gl_je_sources_tl            gjs        
,       fnd_flex_value_sets         ffvs
,       fnd_flex_values             ffv
,       fnd_flex_values_tl          ffvt
,       fnd_flex_value_sets         ffvs2
,       fnd_flex_values             ffv2
,       fnd_flex_values_tl          ffvt2
,       fnd_flex_value_sets         ffvs3
,       fnd_flex_values             ffv3
,       fnd_flex_values_tl          ffvt3
,       ap_invoices_all             api   
,       po_vendors                  pov       
,       po_vendor_sites_all         pvs
,       ap_invoice_payments_all     aip
,       ap_checks_all               aca
,       AP_TERMS_VL                 apt
where   gjb.je_batch_id             = gjh.je_batch_id
and     gjh.je_header_id            = gjl.je_header_id
and     gjl.code_combination_id     = gcc.code_combination_id
and     gjc.je_category_name        = gjh.je_category
and     gjc.language                = 'US'
and     gjs.je_source_name          = gjh.je_source
and     gjs.language                = 'US'
and     ffvs.flex_value_set_id      = ffv.flex_value_set_id
and     ffvs.flex_value_set_name    = XXASW_DISCO_UTIL_PKG.xxasw_get_gl_segment_fvs_name ('SEGMENT2')
and     ffv.flex_value              = gcc.segment2
and     ffv.flex_value_id           = ffvt.flex_value_id
and      ffvt.language               = 'US'
and     ffvs2.flex_value_set_id     = ffv2.flex_value_set_id
and     ffvs2.flex_value_set_name   = XXASW_DISCO_UTIL_PKG.xxasw_get_gl_segment_fvs_name ('SEGMENT3')
and     ffv2.flex_value             = gcc.segment3
and     ffv2.flex_value_id          = ffvt2.flex_value_id
and     ffvt2.language              = 'US'
and     ffvs3.flex_value_set_id     = ffv3.flex_value_set_id
and     ffvs3.flex_value_set_name   =  XXASW_DISCO_UTIL_PKG.xxasw_get_gl_segment_fvs_name ('SEGMENT7') 
and     ffv3.flex_value             = gcc.segment7
and     ffv3.flex_value_id          = ffvt3.flex_value_id
and     ffvt3.language              = 'US'
and     gpd.period_name             = gjh.period_name
and     gpd.period_set_name         = gsb.period_set_name
and     gjh.set_of_books_id         = gsb.set_of_books_id
and     ((gjl.reference_9           <> 'TRADE_REC') 
     or (gjl.reference_9           is null))
and     (case when gjl.reference_6 = 'AP Invoices' 
then to_number(gjl.reference_2) else 0 end ) = api.invoice_id(+) 
and     gjl.reference_5              = api.invoice_num           (+) 
and     pvs.vendor_id               = pov.vendor_id     (+)
and     api.vendor_site_id          = pvs.vendor_site_id (+)
and     api.invoice_id                = aip.invoice_id      (+)          
and     aip.check_id                 = aca.check_id    (+) 
and   api.terms_id                    =       apt.term_id      (+) 
and     ((aca.status_lookup_code    = 'NEGOTIABLE') 
     or (aca.status_lookup_code    is null))
and     aip.reversal_inv_pmt_id(+)  is null 
and gcc.segment3  = 5221
and gjh.period_name  = 'JAN-16'
and gcc.segment2 between 592712 and 592712
and gcc.segment3 between 0000 and 9999;
```

Comment: Remove 5 items at the time, to see when the error disappears.

Comment: HI jarlh, I had already done this. It doesn't work. As the below comment i thought it may be the case but its not...

Comment: So you query doesn't run if you have only one column left, and one table? If that's the case I'd say that is the problem column!

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-01722: invalid number

occurs when you are trying to convert a string into a number, but that string can't be converted for some reason.

Looks like the culprit in your query is the following:

```
and     (case when gjl.reference_6 = 'AP Invoices' 
then to_number(gjl.reference_2) else 0 end ) = api.invoice_id(+)
```

This implies a data issue in `gl_je_lines.reference_2`, there is a string value in that column you aren't expecting.

I'd address this by checking the data in that column `select reference_2 from gl_je_lines` and seeing if anything stands out that would obviously fail conversion.

Comment: HI lathonez, that was my inital thought. But when checking the column there is nothing abnormal about it. The column itself is null but that is the reason this  "and     (case when gjl.reference_6 = 'AP Invoices' 
then to_number(gjl.reference_2) else 0 end ) = api.invoice_id(+)" is used

Comment: Looks like you're using the fact that reference_6 = 'AP Invoices' to infer that reference_2 is not null? Is that always the case?

Comment: hmm, according to [this](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_tonumber), to_number returns null if null is supplied anyway, so it shouldn't be throwing that error.

Comment: Not always there are some invoices that are in this table that are interfaced that the reason of the join...but yes it returns the null values as well but that is why the outer join is used.